# How to combine multiple struct BIOs into a single struct request?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, storage, linux-device-driver, block-device

I'm working on Linux kernel version 2.6.39.1, and am developing a block device driver. In this regard, I want to combine multiple `struct bio`s into a single `struct request`, which is then added to the `request_queue` for processing by the device driver, namely -- `scsi_request_fn()`.

I tried using the `->bi_next` field of `struct bio` to link multiple `struct bio`s that I have composed, thereby creating a linked list of `struct bio`s. When I call `submit_bio()` to submit a bio to the block device layer for I/O, [this](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.39/block/blk-core.c#L1611) `BUG_ON()` is triggered because the code expects `bio->bi_next` to be `NULL`.

Is there a way to link several `struct bio`s into a single `struct request` before sending it to lower layers for servicing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply, @ctuffli. I've decided to use a structure similar to the one described [here](http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+v2.6.39/include/linux/pktcdvd.h#L200). Basically, I allocate a `struct packet_data` which would contain pointers to all `struct bio`s that should be merged to form one single `struct bio` (and later on, one single `struct request`). In addition, I store some driver related information as well in this `struct packet_data`. Next, I allocate a new `struct bio` (lets call it "merged_bio"), copy all the pages from the list of original BIOs and then make the `merged_bio->bi_private` point to the `struct packet_data`. This last hack would allow me to keep track of the list of original BIOs, and also call `bio_endio()` to end I/O on all individual BIOs once the `merged_bio` has been successfully transferred.

Not sure if this is the smartest way to do this, but it does what I intended! :^)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to string multiple `struct bio` together, but you might want to take a look at the "task collector" implementation in [libsas](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/drivers/scsi/libsas/) and the [aic94xx](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/drivers/scsi/aic94xx/) driver for an alternate approach. There isn't much documentation, but the libsas [documentation](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/Documentation/scsi/libsas.txt) describes it as

> Some hardware (e.g. aic94xx) has the capability to DMA more
>    than one task at a time (interrupt) from host memory.  Task
>    Collector Mode is an optional feature for HAs which support
>    this in their hardware.  (Again, it is completely optional
>    even if your hardware supports it.)
>
> In Task Collector Mode, the SAS Layer would do *natural*
>    coalescing of tasks and at the appropriate moment it would
>    call your driver to DMA more than one task in a single HA
>    interrupt. DMBS may want to use this by insmod/modprobe
>    setting the lldd_max_execute_num to something greater than 1.

Effectively, this lets the block layer (a.k.a. BIO) remain unchanged, but multiple requests are accumulated at the driver layer and submitted together.